# Displaying measured grids in ArcGIS Pro 1.4?

Tags: grids-graticules, arcgis-pro

Is it really not possible to display reference grids in an ArcGIS Pro 1.4 layout view ie Eastings & Northings?

At the moment there only seems to be an option for graticules. The ESRI support webpage (http://support.esri.com/technical-article%5C000012529) mentions that it's not been implemented yet, it seems strange to not include this as an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ArcGIS Pro 2.0 has now been released and one of its new features is the [refererence/measured] grids that you are seeking.  They were not available in ArcGIS Pro 1.x.

For an introduction to them see [Add and modify grids](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/layouts/add-and-modify-grids.htm):

> A grid is a network of evenly spaced horizontal and vertical lines
>   used to identify locations on a map. You can use grids to display
>   measured locations using projected coordinates on the map. There are
>   numerous ways to display measured grids. For example, you can create a
>   grid on a map frame depicting a 10,000-meter grid using the universal
>   transverse Mercator (UTM) coordinate system.

Answer (score 2):

Grids will be supported starting with ArcGIS Pro 2.0.
See the [beta announcement](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2017/04/27/arcgis-pro-2-0-beta-coming-soon/) indicating grid support.